# pthread_condattr_setclock not found on ARM

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, wait

I am working on a project which uses `pthread_condattr_setclock` to set clock monotonically but it is not supported by the arm architecture I am working on. How can I manually implement this function?

Comment: The operating system is linux.

Comment: I just want to myself implement this function. the purpose is to set the clock monotonic so I can use pthread_cond_timedwait.

Comment: And compiler is arm-gcc, this function is available for gcc though but not for arm-gcc.

Comment: Are you using uClibc or something? `pthread_cond_setattr` is definitely supported on any properly working libc on Linux as of more than a decade ago.

Comment: Yeah for me it says undefined reference. Is there a way to implement it ?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to backport stuff to the ancient thread library uclibc is using, but it will be nontrivial.